# d3.js undefined data value in callback function click event

Tags: d3.js, events, callback

I'm trying to pass a value to a d3 click event bind to a group composed of a circle and a letter. However this value remains '*undefined*' in the callback function. On the other hand if I pass the same value to another function of the same group, such as .text(d => d.value) that works fine. The issue is only with the click event. Please find my piece of code:

```
//The parent svg
var s = d3.select("#"+this.id) //this refers to the current object
        .append("svg")
        .attr("id",this.svgid)
        .attr("width","100%")
        .attr("height","100%");

//The value to be passed to the click event
const dd = [{value:"whatever"}];
            
var group1 = s.data(dd).append("svg:g");

//First element of the group = a circle
group1.append("svg:circle")
        .attr("cx","85%")
        .attr("cy","20%")
        .attr("r","10px")
        .attr("fill","#FFFFFF");

//Second element of the group = letter i
group1.append("svg:text").text("i")
        .attr("x","85%")
        .attr("y","25%")
        .attr("fill","#555555");

group1.append("svg:text").text(d => d.value).attr("x","50%").attr("y","50%");//This line works fine

group1.on("click",d => console.log(d.value));//This line returns 'undefined'--> Why?
```

I tried several flavors of the callback function such function(d){console.log(d.value);} but without success. Any idea?

Comment: Do you use D3 V6?

Comment: I use D3 V6.7.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace

`group1.on("click",d => console.log(d.value));`

with

`group1.on("click",(e, d) => console.log(d.value));`

Since D3 V6, event is passed as the first argument to the mouse event callbacks

Comment: Solved. Thank you Michael, you've made my day